# Renaming directory and some of the containing files/subdirectories

Tags: java, file-io, file-rename

I'm recently making some Java software to find some files/directories in a folder that if their name contains certain text, they will be renamed to some other name. I use `Files.walkFileTree` to traversal the directories and if found one file/directories matched, it will be renamed by using `File.renameTo` method.

But here I met a problem if one sub directory has been renamed, all the renaming operations under this sub directory will fail.

I think it was caused by that this sub directory has been marked open, so no change can be made for its files/folders. Any idea to solve that?

Answer (score 3):

This would happen if all the names are determined first and then you rename the directory before renaming the files it contains.

A couple of was around this is to rename files depth first (only rename the directory after renaming the files) or only build the list of files as you go.

Answer (score 1):

This might be solved by renaming directories from 'the bottom most first to topmost last'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is what the semantic of `walkFileTree` supposed to be. Alan Bateman, tech leader of NIO 2 said:

> The walkFileTree utility method is an internal iterator that makes use
>   of iterators obtained from directory streams. These iterators are 
>   specified (in DirectoryStream) to be "weakly consistent" and may not 
>   reflect updates to the directory after the directory is opened. ...
>   Anyway, the reason for the difference is that the underlying implementation
>   is very different.